# Different PHP modes for Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: centos7, httpd, fastcgi, cgi, cms

I got LAMP stack installed on Centos 7. Also I have three CMS up and running on httpd virtual hosts: WordPress, Joomla and OpenCart.

The question: how to configure different PHP modes, CGI and FCGI per virtual host?
I have separate .conf files per CMS.

PHP Version 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple php-fpm pools with different configs should accomplish what you are asking for.